# Рандом с помощью bind

Tags: c++

а как можно рандомное число в вектор записать ?

```
int lo{ 0 };
int hi{ 100 };
std::vector <int> v0;

for (int i{}; i < hi; ++i)
{
    auto ri = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(lo, hi), 
    std::default_random_engine{});
    v0.push_back(ri);
}
```

к сожалению, `v0.push_back(ri)` не работает, а `int ri` тоже не могу записать

```
 random = rand() % 20 + 1;
```

он работает, но хочу понять, как можно с std::bind

Comment: Один только вопрос - зачем?!! Нет, если очень хочется - посмотрите пример тут: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind, внизу страницы, в примерах... но зачем?...

Comment: @Harry ну интересно же )

Comment: std::bind обычно используется для создания функторов, которые потом еще и вызывать нужно.

Answer (score 1):

я тормоз  `v0.push_back(ri());` и все будет работать ....